# Error al copiar un archivo en java

Tags: java

Lo que pretendo hacer es copiar la imagen dentro de la carpeta directorio pero cuando ejecuto el metodo no pasa nada de eso sino que el directorio se convierte en un arhivo que debo hacer para que me funcione?

```
public static void copyFile(String origen, String destino) throws IOException {
    Path FROM = Paths.get(origen);//img/imagen1.jpg
    Path TO = Paths.get(destino);//img/directorio
      System.out.println("from: "+ FROM);
      System.err.println("TO: "+ TO);
//        sobreescribir el fichero de destino, si existe, y copiar
//        los atributos, incluyendo los permisos rwx
    CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
      StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
      StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
    }; 
    Files.copy(FROM, TO, options);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

El segundo parámetro debe indicar la **ruta final/objetivo** en donde vas a guardar el archivo, no el directorio en donde lo quieres guardar. `Files#copy` lo que hará es copiar o reeplazar un archivo, por eso te solicita la **ruta completa** en donde quieres copiar (incluído el nombre de archivo final). Por defecto, si no especificas `StandarCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING` y si el archivo existe, la copia fallará.

```
Paths origen = Paths.get("/home/usuario/archivo.pdf");
Paths objetivo = Paths.get("/home/usuario/Documentos/archivo-final.pdf");
CopyOption[] options = new CopyOption[]{
    StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING,
    StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES
}; 
Files.copy(origen, objetivo, options);
```